# Rails - How to set expired date on voucher rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have Voucher model with expired date inside..

Here's the codes:

```
rails generate model Voucher

rails generate add_expired_date_to_vouchers expired_date:datetime
```

> ```
> In voucher index:
>
> <% if voucher.expired_date == Date.today %>
>   <p>Your Voucher has Expired</p>
> <% else %>
>   <%= voucher.expired_date %>
> <% end %>
> ```

Problem is :
When voucher's expired is today, it still show expired date, Not "Your voucher has expired"..

Please Help me to solve this problem..

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a `DateTime` object with `Date` which ain't gonna work. Probably you should **transform** `DateTime` into `Date`.

**Example:**

```
2.3.7 :006 > a = DateTime.now.to_date
 => Sun, 23 Sep 2018 
2.3.7 :007 > b = Date.today
 => Sun, 23 Sep 2018 
2.3.7 :008 > a == b
 => true
```

So the below code should work

```
<% if voucher.expired_date.to_date == Date.today %>
  <p>Your Voucher has Expired</p>
<% else %>
  <%= voucher.expired_date %>
<% end %>
```

Or

You should compare a `DateTime` with a `DateTime`.

```
<% if voucher.expired_date == DateTime.now %>
  <p>Your Voucher has Expired</p>
<% else %>
  <%= voucher.expired_date %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i got this error undefined method `to_date' for nil:NilClass when i tried the first one.

Comment: @Garbela Check whether that voucher has an `expired_date` value in the DB.It should not be nil

Comment: the codes work on show.html.erb, but not working on index.html.erb because loop ( @vouchers.each do |voucher| )

Answer (score 0):

The condition's operator you are using is not correct !

```
<% if voucher.expired_date >= Date.today %> #if today is a valid day only use >
  <p>Your Voucher has Expired</p>
<% else %>
  <%= voucher.expired_date %>
<% end %>
```